# Why is $\operatorname{Ext}^0(A,B)\simeq \operatorname{Hom}(A,B)$?

Tags: homology-cohomology

I want to prove

> $\operatorname{Ext}^0(A,B)\simeq \operatorname{Hom}(A,B)$ where $A,B$ are modules over some ring $R$.

My definition of $\operatorname{Ext}^n(A,B)=H^n(\operatorname{Hom}(C,B))$ where $\operatorname{Hom}(C,B) = \{\operatorname{Hom}(C_n,B),\delta^n\}$ where $C_n$ is a canonical free resolution of $A$.
So I need to show $\operatorname{Hom}(A,B) = \operatorname{ker}(\delta^0)$ for $\operatorname{Hom}(C_0,B)\xrightarrow{\delta^0}\operatorname{Hom}(C_1,B)$. But I can't see where the equivalence rises. Could you help? It seems this fact is accepted as an obvious fact but not to me.

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see the [guidelines for good use of $\rm\LaTeX$ in question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730).

Comment: @Christoph I don't think so. My definition uses free resolution so I want to prove without injective resolution or projective resolution (and book didn't introduced that term.).

Comment: @PeterJohn Free resolutions are projective resolutions, so those answers that use projective resolutions should work for you.

Comment: This question has actually nothing to do with free or projective resolutions. The question simply is: “Why is $\operatorname{Hom}(-,B)$ left exact?”